# The repository can't find what it saved

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Entity:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
public class OveroptimisationIdentifierEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Getter
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255)")
    private UUID id;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(unique = true)
    private LocalDate date;
}
```

Repository:

```
import java.util.UUID;

public interface OveroptimisationIdentifierRepository extends JpaRepository<OveroptimisationIdentifierEntity, UUID> {
    OveroptimisationIdentifierEntity findFirstByOrderByDateDesc();
}
```

Create:

```
public OveroptimisationIdentifierEntity createIdentifier() {
    OveroptimisationIdentifierEntity identifier = OveroptimisationIdentifierEntity.builder().build();
    try {
        overoptimisationIdentifierRepository.save(identifier);
    } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
// Date must be unique. Find the tuple with the current date, delete it, and save the entity anew.
        OveroptimisationIdentifierEntity currentIdentifier = overoptimisationIdentifierRepository.findFirstByOrderByDateDesc(); // Breakpoing.
        arsenkinOveroptimisationIdentifierRepository.delete(currentIdentifier);
        overoptimisationIdentifierRepository.save(identifier);
    }

    return identifier;
}
```

I have created an identifier with the method above. It really worked: I can see that identifier in the database. But it was a case for a clear database.

Then I try to create another identifier. But I get this exception:

https://dpaste.org/MBry7

I have put a breakpoint (signified in the code). The debugger stops at the breakpoint.

The attempt to find the identifier in the database:

[image]

Even `findAll` doesn't work:

```
overoptimisationIdentifierRepository.findAll()
```

[image]

Why can the repository not find what it saved itself? And how should I modify the code for it to be able to work?

Comment: ...because(why?) there is no `@Setter` on id!?!? ;)

Comment: @xerx593, thank you for your answer. I modified my question. That is I added Data. It has not helped.

Comment: ok, it was subtle hope :) (then, next) problem is: "I have created an identifier with the method above. It really worked: I can see that identifier in the database. But it was a case for a clear database." ...which means: "your old data (definition) doesn't match (new) mapping"

Comment: @xerx593, pardon. I can't understand what new mapping? It is the same repository. Why it can't find what it created?

Comment: Java says it cant cast String to UUID, try implement a `setId(String id)`

Comment: @hillel_guy , I think it is a bit error prone. If the problem is really in the type, I'd better not to us it as an ID. But this is UUID, isn't it natural to be used as ID?

Comment: I see that there is also a way to instruct hibernate to store the UUID correctly in the DB using this annotation on top of the ID field, perhaps it will help `@Type(type="uuid-char")`